# update mailmerge field after aspose.words.Document.getMailMerge().execute

Tags: java, aspose, aspose.words

this is my first question here so bear with me please.

I have an `aspose.words.Document` object with mailmerge fields. I need to change one of the fields more than one time. As far as I know once you change a `MailMerge` field with `Document.getMailMerge().execute`, the field becomes plain text and stop being a field. Thats because when I use these lines of code again with different values, it doesn't work for a second time.

```
doc.getMailMerge().execute(
                new String[] { "title", "name", "address", "telephone", "fax", "date" },

                new Object[] { "Some title", "some name", "some address", "some telephone", "some fax", "some date" });
```

I have two workarounds for this problem that I'm facing:

One is that I create one more `Document` object and put that object through all the phases with my original `Document` object except for the `doc.MailMerge().execute` phase. However the phases before MailMerge phase cost much time (for big documents) which can be measured with minutes, so I dont want to double that time. I used a performance tool for it.

Second is that right before using `MailMerge()` for the first time, I use `Document.deepClone()` on the original document to create a second independant object. With this I don't need to add those time costly code blocks for a second time, but I also haven't calculated or searched deeply for performance of this `deepClone()` method. I'll add that info after I dig into that.

Long story short what I want to ask is, can I update a MailMerge field after I change it. If not so, is there a better workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I know once you change a MailMerge field with Document.getMailMerge().execute, the field becomes plain text and stop being a field.

Yes, you are right. The fields are filled with data after executing mail merge.

> can I update a MailMerge field after I change it. If not so, is there a better workaround for this

If you want to execute mail merge on same document multiple times, you can either prepare the document again before merging, or create a clone. However, it is faster to prepare the document once and than clone it before each merge.

Please take a look at [How to Produce Multiple Documents during Mail Merge](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsjava/How+to++Produce+Multiple+Documents+during+Mail+Merge).

Disclosure: I am a developer at Aspose.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. If I'm not mistaken what you offer as a better solution is much similar to my second workaround. Actually I also came across the link you shared above, and this link: <a href="http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsjava/Cloning+a+Document" title="clone document">clone document vs prepare document again</a> This link shares the same idea of cloning a document being faster.

Comment: Even if you already have a ready-to-merge document somewhere on disk. It is faster to clone the document as compared to reloading it for each merge.